# if a very large amout the rows are missing in any perticular column is it appropriate to drop it?

Tags: machine-learning, statistical-significance, data-visualization, descriptive-statistics

I am dealing with time series data having a large number of columns, in which some of these columns have 95% of misssing values.

If I drop these columns and continue will that really affect my model's accuracy to a larger extent?

Comment: Perhaps so, perhaps not. That is a very weak answer but I don’t know how a confident, precise answer is possible. What are the alternatives any way?

Comment: There are only 4 such columns among 20 with large amount of missing values..

Comment: if there is any good approach..please help !! i'm new to this..

Comment: The decision should be informed by domain knowledge. What kind of variables are concerned? How many distinct values do they take on in the non-missing entries? Here is just one illustrative scenario : if the missing values follow a certain pattern (e.g. only people with a salary below a certain amount are likely to censor the information they are willing to share), then you could create one meaningful category for all missing entries in such a column. The bottom line is that if the pattern of the missing data can be modelled from domain knowledge or other variables, then you can try stgh.